# unable to play the audio file in the browser

Tags: asp.net, audio, wav

I have a folder named file in my application folder and in that folder i have some .wav files.Below is the code that i used to play the audio file but this is not working the audio is not getting played in the website can anyone help me out with the mistake that i am doing

Actually on dragging the audio i am getting this **file/myTune.wav** and i am passing in this way and this is my final code after running this code i am able to see the audio but it is not getting played

```
 <div>
            <audio controls="controls">
                <source src="file/myTune.wav" type="audio/wav" />
            </audio>
        </div>
```

Can anyone help me out as i am new to this

Comment: What browser are you using? http://caniuse.com/#feat=wav

Comment: i am using chrome browser because internet explorer does not support it

Comment: Unfortunately your code is correct, which means the problem must lay somewhere else. I would suggest to verify the paths and make sure they are correct and the browser has access to the file. The developer tools may help you with that. Good luck!

Comment: Are there any other links which you can suggest me where the code works in playing the .wav files

Comment: As mentioned above your code is correct, as you can see here: http://codepen.io/joseluisbolos/pen/pEYaJq

Comment: if i am using some web links it is working but i need to have audio file in my application folder and i need to pass that as source